# Define constructor for this enum for the list in JAVA?

Tags: java, list, enums

```
public enum Role{ 
    ADMIN("SMITH","KEVIN"),
    STUDENT("JACK", "JILL", "MARRY", "MALA"),
    GURDIAN("BOB");
}
```

How can I define constructor for this enum in JAVA?

Can I initiate as follows?

```
Role(List<String> userlist){}
```

Comment: You can use a `String...` varargs here, but not a `List` directly as it won't match the signature.

Comment: If you need a `List<String>` while maintaining the signature (and thus using varargs as already suggested), have a look at `Arrays.asList(...)`.

Comment: bad design. what are you going to do if you later on want to add or remove an admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use variable arguments varargs in constructor like:

```
public enum Role {

    ADMIN("SMITH","KEVIN"),
    STUDENT("JACK", "JILL", "MARRY", "MALA"),
    GURDIAN("BOB");

    private Role(String...name) {
        this.values = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The most suitable constructor I can think of is with a `String` varargs, as follows:

```
Role(String... names) {
    // TODO
}
```

A constructor taking `List<String>` will not match the signature and will not compile on its own.

You can always overload the constructors though.

Comment: Overloading the constructor won't be very useful in this case, since it's an `enum` and will only ever be created in this very file, so not a lot is gained from having an additional `Role(List<String>)` constructor. I do like the pattern as a general rule.

Comment: @daniu I agree, as an afterthought it is kind of pointless. The overloaded constructor can be used internally, but I can't think of a case where it would matter.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely go with the varargs style constructor

```
private final List<String> values;
Role(String... values) {
  this.values = Arrays.asList(values);
} 

public List<String> getValues() {
    return values;
}
```

And then when you need the particular role based on the provided names go for the find as

```
public static Role find(String name) {
for (Role role: Role.values()) {
    if (rol.getValues().contains(name)) {
        return rol;
    }
}
return null;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum Role{ 
    ADMIN("SMITH","KEVIN"),
    STUDENT("JACK", "JILL", "MARRY", "MALA"),
    GURDIAN("BOB");

    private String[] values;

    Role(String ... values) {
         this.values = values;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is declaration (in enum), storage in field, and usage.

As these are singletons, defined in the enum class, the form of the declaration is only important with respect to elegance.

```
public enum Role{ 
    ADMIN(user("SMITH", "KEVIN")),
    STUDENT(user("JACK", "JILL"), user("MARRY", "MALA")),
    GURDIAN(user("BOB"));

    // Local factory methods
    // User or Principal
    private User user(String firstname, String surname) { ... }
    private User user(String firstname) { ---}

    private final Set<User> users;

    Role(User... users) {
        if (users.length == 1) { ...
        }
        this.users = new HashSet<>();
        Collections.addAll(users);
    }

    public boolean ...(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```